# 3 div's: 2 toggles, 1 toggle with outside click close on ios

Tags: android, jquery, ios, html, toggle

Thanks for reading and help! I have 3 div's. One is the menu div, which I like to be toggled by clicking on the menu (show/hide) AND by clicking outside the div when it is shown (only hide).

The other two divs are extra info div's which can be shown/hidden only by the toggle. I don't want them to be closed when you click outside the shown div's.

Here's the setup: 
HTML

```
<a id="menu_slide">MENU</a>    
<div id="menu_info"><a href="#">HOME</a> | <a href="#">PROFILE</a> | <a href="#">FORUM</a></div>
<br><br>
<a id="nextpart_slide">TOGGLE 1</a>
<div id="nextpart_info">Hello bla bla bla</div>

<a id="nextpart_slide2">TOGGLE 2</a>
<div id="nextpart_info2">Hello bla bla bla</div>
```

JQUERY

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#menu_slide').click(function () {
      jQuery('#menu_info').slideToggle('2000',"swing", function () {
      });
  });

  jQuery('#nextpart_slide').click(function () {
      jQuery('#nextpart_info').slideToggle('2000',"swing", function () {
      });
  });

  jQuery('#nextpart_slide2').click(function () {
      jQuery('#nextpart_info2').slideToggle('2000',"swing", function () {
      });
  });


});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/HSdaG/1/
Very basic toggle function thus, but here's the question: 
1. How to make menu div close when I click outside the div? While keeping the other two div's in their current state.
2. How to make this work on ios/android devices as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### HTML

```
<div id="menu_container">
    <a id="menu_slide">MENU</a>    
    <div id="menu_info"><a href="#">HOME</a> | <a href="#">PROFILE</a> | <a href="#">FORUM</a></div>
    <br><br>
    <a id="nextpart_slide">TOGGLE 1</a>
    <div id="nextpart_info">Hello bla bla bla</div>

    <a id="nextpart_slide2">TOGGLE 2</a>
    <div id="nextpart_info2">Hello bla bla bla</div>
</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#menu_container').click(function (event) {
        //code goes here
    });

    jQuery('#menu_slide').click(function (event) {
        jQuery('#menu_info').slideToggle('2000',"swing", function () {
        });
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    jQuery('#nextpart_slide').click(function (event) {
        jQuery('#nextpart_info').slideToggle('2000',"swing", function () {
        });
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    jQuery('#nextpart_slide2').click(function (event) {
        jQuery('#nextpart_info2').slideToggle('2000',"swing", function () {
        });
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

You would have to have menu_container be bigger than the other divs. What would happen is when you click inside the other divs, the event fires within the smallest div first, and then it goes outside to the div it's contained in, etc. etc. By calling event.stopPropagation(), you're preventing the event from firing in the next-biggest divs. So the click in the menu_container wouldn't be called if you clicked inside any of the smaller divs. But if you click inside the menu_container and not in the children divs then its click function would be called since event.stopPropagation() wasn't called by the other events.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I click inside #menu_container (to click on a menu link) it will toggle #menu_container again, is that correct? Wouldn't be easier to check on a click, if #menu_container is shown and if click is outside #menu_container and then close #menu_container? http://jsfiddle.net/HSdaG/3/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to rweichler I figured it out. This is the working jQuery code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('html').click(function() {
       jQuery('#menu_info').hide(); 
});

    jQuery('#menu_slide').click(function (event) {
        jQuery('#menu_info').slideToggle('2000',"swing", function () {
        });
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    jQuery('#nextpart_slide').click(function (event) {
        jQuery('#nextpart_info').slideToggle('2000',"swing", function () {
        });
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    jQuery('#nextpart_slide2').click(function (event) {
        jQuery('#nextpart_info2').slideToggle('2000',"swing", function () {
        });
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

See it at work at: http://jsfiddle.net/HSdaG/4/

Thanks!